# Icon Based Navigation Bootstrap & Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, navigation

I am creating a mobile app with jQuery Mobile and Twitter Bootstrap. I am trying to accomplish a "springboard" like application navigation. I have 6 icons that I want in two rows of 3.

I currently have:

```
             <li><img src="img/info.png" /></li>
             <li><img src="img/map.png" /></li>
             <li><img src="img/rules.png" /></li>
             <li><img src="img/calender.png" /></li>
             <li><img src="img/iSchool.png" /></li>
             <li><img src="img/Infinite-Campus.png" /></li>
```

I want to make it feel like Apple's Springboard, but with larger icons and a more Windows Phone Metro feel. Can this be accomplished with these frameworks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `glyphicon` **[classes](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)** (assuming that you have added the fonts from Bootstrap) and specify font sizes for your icons:

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-nameoficon></span></li>
    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-nameoficon></span></li>
    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-nameoficon></span></li>
    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-nameoficon></span></li>
    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-nameoficon></span></li>
    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-nameoficon></span></li>  
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav span{
    font-size:40px;
}
```

If you haven't added the fonts folder, this is how your folder structure would look like:

```
project/fonts
project/css/styles.css
```

Basically the fonts folder has to be one level "up" from your styles.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have 6 small images with icons in them.

Comment: Maybe you could create a svg version of the icons and then use icomoon.io for example to create an icon font set ? That's the only thing that I can think of. And if serving the fonts is an issue, I am sure there are services out there that CDN your fonts too...